# Al Jazeera sports application geolocation problems for iPad

Tags: ipad, geolocation

I have an app for Al Jazeera sports. I have a subscription with them on the app, and now I'm going to the USA to study and I need to watch the games on my iPad since I'll have no TV access when the games are played. Is there a tweak that I can do through iFile to trick the app to think that I am in the Middle East? It works if I change the IP address to a Saudi web proxy, but its not reliable, not always online, and becomes slower. If you want to test the application, you'll need to get it from a middle eastern Apple Store.

Answer (score 1):

If the Al Jazeera apps determines your location based on your IP address (which seems to be the case), the only way to circumvent this check is by using a proxy or VPN connection with an IP address in an allowed range.